# How to insert HTML with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a context menu option and when it is selected I want insert some HTML. I have tried doing this

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerText='test123';
```

But it's not working for me.

*Note* I am trying to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: Your content script event listener runs in a background page; you are manipulating that background page instead of the page open in the browser's active tab.  Manipulation of a tab's page must be done by a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). The background page can use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to signal when the content script should act. (Alternatively, you can create a kind of on-the-fly content script using [`executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).)

Comment: It works for me when I run it in the console but not in the extenstion. Could you send me your file so I can look over it, see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I think @DesertIvy was confirming that your script is correctly formulated, not necessarily that you are running it in the correct place within your extension's structure.

Comment: I see, I'm reading up on content-scripts right now. Hopefully I can get this to work soon.

Comment: You just need to put your code in a `content.js` file in your extension, and in your click handler do `chrome.tabs.executeScript( {file: 'content.js'} );`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) you can research how to create an extension and download the sample manifest.json.

[**Content Scripts**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can be used to run js/css matching certain urls.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Append Test Text",
  "description": "Add test123 to body",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Append Test Text"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
var div=document.createElement("div"); 
document.body.appendChild(div); 
div.innerText="test123";
```

The above will execute the `content-script.js` for all urls matching `http://*/*` where `*` is a wildcard. so basically all `http` pages.

Content scripts have many properties which can be found in the link above.

[**Programmatic injection**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) can be used when js/css shouldn't be injected into every page that matches the pattern.

Below shows how to execute the js `onclick` of the extension icon:-

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Append Test Text",
  "description": "Add test123 to body",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Append Test Text"
  },
  "manifest_version": 1
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'var div=document.createElement("div"); document.body.appendChild(div); div.innerText="test123";'
  });
});
```

This uses the [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) method, which also has an option to call a separate file like so:-

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "insert.js"
  });
});
```

**insert.js**

```
var div=document.createElement("div"); 
document.body.appendChild(div); 
div.innerText="test123";
```

Comment: > js onclick of the extension icon

is the manifest file here incomplete? How would you be clicking on an icon when there is no page_action or files declared.