# With Chrome Extension: Is there a way to play animations on the YouTube html5 Player on keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I want to make a chrome extension for myself that adds custom animations to the YouTube Player (like the play/pause animation that pops up in the middle of the screen). I'm not sure quite how to approach this, and I was hoping you guys could help.

I was thinking that I could have some html that loads on youtube pages, and it creates an opacity:0 element that is positioned absolutely to the video player. And then I'd have a keylistener, and when I pressed a certain key, the element would go through a @keyframes animation from opacity:0 to opacity:1 and then back to opacity:0.

I'm struggling because I'm not sure how to insert html onto existing web pages - I was looking into js .createElement and .appendChild, but it seems like there is a better way.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate [How to insert HTML with a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103183/how-to-insert-html-with-a-chrome-extension)