# Chrome extension: How does honey extension dropdown upon checkout?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know how honey extension drops upon checkout?

I want to do the same for my extension where once timer is done it dropdowns. However, can't find anywhere that teaches it.

[image: I have the following timer code:]

Comment: It's a normal DOM element added in the content script. Use the built-in devtools to inspect  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page that pops up when you click the extension is called the "pop up". There is no way to programmatically do this so that it's automatic or based on a timer
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30491

The popup that honey uses is actually just an element that is inserted into the page. You can actually view this with Inspect Element. It adds a `<div>` right after the `</body>` tag

You should create a background service, then add an element to the page when your timer is expired

Comment: That perfectly makes sense. So do you mean I should append a `<div>` element? I belive from content.js not background as background doesn't have access to popup.html if I am not wrong

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with chrome extensions, but you should probably have a background.js script that continuously runs, then from that script, you can add elements to a page. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103183/how-to-insert-html-with-a-chrome-extension

Comment: can you add it to all the tabs of a user after a certain action? (example after timer finishes). if not, can you just add to the current tab of the user not the original one or the one where user clicked on the extension first

Comment: I'm not sure. Chrome's extension apis are not very well documented. Looks like they're trying to get rid of the tabs feature. I'm sure you can figure out a way. Maybe look at the chrome activeTab api. Is this for your own website or does this need to work on any website? If it's your own, I would suggest making this apart of the website